# iptables-persistent doesn't load rules on boot

Tags: boot, iptables

I have few iptables rules which I want to use permanently. So I've installed iptables-persistent and save my rules in /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and /etc/iptables/rules.v6.

Also I turn on autostart for iptables-persistent service

```
$ sudo update-rc.d iptables-persistent defaults
$ sudo update-rc.d iptables-persistent enable 2345
```

But after system starts iptables rules are still empty

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And when I start iptables-persistent manually, it goes well

```
$ sudo service iptables-persistent start
 * Loading iptables rules...
 * IPv4...
 * IPv6...

$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source                destination         
DROP       all  --  domain.ru             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  srv246-131.domain.ru  anywhere
etc ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that iptables-persistent calls iptables-restore during bootup before the network is initialised. Therefore you cannot do dns-lookups at this point.

You either have to use the ip-address instead of a domain name or load the domain-related rules at a later time e.g. via rc.local.