# Iptables not loading at boot

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 as a firewall with iptables.

I have a network interface like this:

```
iface lo inet loopback
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

This method has been working for years, but not anymore. My firewall is up to date.
I also enabled logging:

```
iface lo inet loopback
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules > /var/log/iptables-boot.log
```

but it's empty.

I also tried it with a script at  /etc/network/if-up.d/script:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules >> /var/log/iptables_boot.log
echo "iptables loaded" >> /var/log/iptables_boot.log
```

Where, the logfile only contains "iptables loaded" but nothing else. That means the script runs, but no iptables rules are added to the kernel.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: When asking about iptables, it is helpful if you post your rules ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your iptables configuration is not loading. It could be because you are using domain names, rather then ip address

IMO easiest "solution" is to use `iptables-persistent`

First, configure or load your rules (you will be asked to save the current set of rules as a part of the install)

Then run

```
sudo apt-get -y install iptables-persistent
```

For additional information, including modifying your rules in the future,  See
 http://www.microhowto.info/howto/make_the_configuration_of_iptables_persistent_on_debian.html

and (for ip address vs. domain name)

[iptables-persistent doesn't load rules on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246578/iptables-persistent-doesnt-load-rules-on-boot)

Comment: Hi, yes I've found 'iptables-persistent' but I think it is a workaround. I'd like to know why this happens. How can I debug this loading? I don't use hostnames in iptables, only IP addresses!

Comment: If you need help, post your iptables rules, otherwise it is next to impossible to guess. Could be http://askubuntu.com/questions/246578/iptables-persistent-doesnt-load-rules-on-boot for all I know ;) iptables-persistent is not really a "work around" as ubuntu uses ufw, and not iptables by default.  iptables-persistent is the default way Debian/Ubuntu saves iptables rules by default (it is not installed as ufw is preferred). rpm systems use alternate methods.

Comment: I really don't want to post my iptables rules as there are about 1200lines. nobody would read it. If I run the "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules" command, then it works fine and loads all the rules from the file. This means to me that there is no problem with the rules.

Comment: Is there something that could reset the iptables rules? I have a thought that the rules are loaded, but after that, they are being flushed. What do you think?

Comment: pastebin your rule set and post a link back here if you need help. 1200 lines sounds excessive and there is likely a way of simplifying your rules. My other guess is that you are using domain names rather then ip addresses.I am guessing you are blocking certain sites and iptables ls likely not the best tool, but hard to say. See also http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables

Comment: Hi, I never use domain names in iptables rules.